# Disable window decoration for specific applications

Tags: window-manager, titlebar

Is there a way to configure the window manager to disable window decorations (title bar, preferably no borders either) to specific applications (based on the name of the app, title of the window, or anything similar...)?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Do you want to know if your existing WM can do what you want? Or are you looking for another WM that can do what you have mentioned?

Comment: Preferably the first, if not then any WM will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Compiz/Unity, you can do this from the infamous [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/), but it's a bit tricky.

The "Decoration Match" key in the Window Decoration plugin specifies the windows that *do* have decorations. To selectively disable window decorations you have to construct an expression that matches every window *except* the ones you want to disable.

For example, if you want to disable window decorations for windows whose titles end in "Mozilla Firefox" or "Chromium", you can set the decoration match to:

`(!title=Mozilla Firefox$) & (!title=Chromium$)`

Complete documentation for Compiz window matching is at http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching

Comment: any tip for 14.04? unfortunately "window decoration" conflicts with "ubuntu unity plugin"

Answer (score 2):

You can disable/enable you title bar with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from gtk.gdk import *

w=window_foreign_new((get_default_root_window().property_get("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW")[2][0])

if w.get_decorations() == 0 :
    w.set_decorations(DECOR_ALL)
else:
    w.set_decorations(0)

window_process_all_updates()
```

It comes from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dirtslayer/3780188).
That is based on this post about [removing decoration on specific WMs](https://xrunhprof.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/removing-decoration-in-xfwm-or-metacity-again/).

As it is mentioned in the article, you can create a shortcut to remove decoration of the windows you are interested in.